# Unable to view uploaded images from IE11

Tags: file-uploads, image

When uploading images to EE v2.7.2 from IE11 the images cannot be seen after uploading is completed. All other browsers seem to work properly.

Comment: Is this the regular file field or an add-on?  
.

Answer (score 1):

There: "... All other browsers seem to work properly", fixed :-).

Does explorer have a firebug/devtools like console?
Try to inspect the network response, notices in there.